# Filtering and then reassigning navigation properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net

I'm writing a piece of this website that handles list filtering.  User selects some options, and the data is filtered server-side and set back to the user through an AJAX request.

For this example, say I have a table of car manufacturers (Ford, BMW, Fiat, etc) and it has a foreign key to a list of all their vehicles, which in turn has a foreign key to a table of vehicle types.

So it'd be like this:

**Manufacturer**

- ManufacturerID
- Name

**Type**

- TypeID
- Name

**Vehicle**

- VehicleID
- ManufacturerID
- TypeID
- Name

This would come back as a nice entity and some convenient navigation properties.  However, this is the problem I'm facing: Say I want to filter a manufacturer's vehicles based on their type, inline.

```
foreach (var manufacturer in manufacturers)
{
    manufacturer.Vehicles = manufacturer.Vehicles.Any(v => v.Type.Name == "Car"));
}
```

This seems pretty straightforward but I get the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Casting to EntityCollection doesn't help, and throws an exception at run time.  Is it even possible to assign the result of a Linq query to a navigation property?  Is there another way of doing this?  I'm using a ViewModel but I'd like to re-use the navigation properties if I can, instead of, perhaps, writing in a dictionary and handling it all manually.

Answer (score 0):

The problems is that the **manufacturer.Vehicles**'s type is **EntityCollection** and **manufacturer.Vehicles.Any** returns  an objet of type **IEnumerable**, so you want to try as follows:

```
foreach ( manufacturer in manufacturers) {
   manufacturer.Vehicles = (from vehicle in manufacturer.Vehicleswhere vehicle.Type.Name == "Car");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that effectively do the same thing, just a different way?

Comment: No because the returned type implements IEntityWithRelationships not IEnumerable.

Comment: Hm, it still comes back as IEnumerable for me when I try it this way.

Comment: Model first, technically it's just ADO.NET, no EntityFramework.

Comment: So then try adding .ToList at the end of the query:

manufacturer.Vehicles = (from vehicle in manufacturer.Vehicleswhere vehicle.Type.Name == "Car").ToList

and tell me what happend